# How can I access a class passed to a WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I'm passing a class to a WPF Window, and binding properties of the class to fields in the WPF Window.  I have that working fine, but I want to edit a property of the class, show the changes in the WPF Window, and then return the class back to the application that called the WPF Window.

Here is the code to display the WPF Window.  When I try to access newproduct from the RewriteTitle method I cannot.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Inventory_Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TitleWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TitleWindow : Window
    {
        public TitleWindow(Product newproduct)
        {
            this.DataContext = newproduct;  //This didn't help

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void RewriteTitle(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Here I want to access newproduct 


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: You pass an object instance to the window, not a class. The object instance is of some type (the type being a class), but the object instance itself is not the class. Objects vs. classes/types -- not the same. (Confusingly, .NET has a class/type that is named `Object`, so yeah, there can be an object instance of the class `Object`. Well, what can i say...)

Comment: With such a vaguely stated problem and practically no code, it's impossible to know exactly what answer is appropriate for you. But: why not just get the data context value you already saved, back as the `Product` type? E.g. `Product newproduct = (Product)DataContext;`

Comment: I'm not sure what was vague.  As elgonzo pointed out, my terminology is off.  

I'm passing an instance of an object to a WPF Window.  I want to access that instance with code behind the WPF Window and I can't.  Product newproduct = (Product)DataContext; doesn't seem to do anything to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Can you update your question with `Product` model?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is using the private field. You should create a private readonly field to set the value.

```
    public TitleWindow(Product newproduct)
    {
        this.DataContext = newproduct; 

        _product = newproduct;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private readonly Product _product;
```

And then you can find the `_product` in RewriteTitle

```
    private void RewriteTitle(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Here I want to access newproduct 
        // Use _product = xx Or _product.Foo = xx;

    }
```

Comment: _product does not exist in the current context when I do this.  I also had to initialize the _product = newproduct; with Product _producte = newproduct;

Comment: @StephenHenry Are you sure, that you write `private readonly Product _product;` in class code block, not in `TitleWindow` ctor code block?